# Tomcat 9 not executing setenv.sh on start up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, java, tomcat

I've created setenv.sh to my CATALINA_BASE folder which is at /usr/share/tomcat9/ but the setenv.sh is in /usr/share/tomcat9/bin

setenv.sh content:

```
echo "HELLO ITS WORKING"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
```

I've made the script executable with chmod +x, but when I restart Tomcat and check the logs, there is no mention about these "flags" or the echo that is in the script. This is what logs say:

```
options used: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat9 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat9 -Djava.endorsed.dirs= -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat9/temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

Also, I don't have other start up scripts such as catalina.sh etc. I only have the setenv.sh

**Do I need to set catalina.sh also?

Is my CATALINA_BASE folder wrong?

Or maybe setenv.sh needs permissions to execute?**

Comment: I have the same problem. Running Tomcat 9.0.54 on Java 17 on Amazon Linux 2. This worked very well on a slightly different installation (Tomcat 9.0.50 on Java 11 on RHEL). Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

setenv.sh probably needs to be under $CATALINA_BASE/bin
The bin directory should already exist.